# Does Node require load entire the module first, even if you only use one part of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

When we have this syntax

```
const { somePart } = require('./someModule');
```

Does the compiler loads entire module in RAM to get that part?
Consider that `somePart` is a small amount of code, while `someModule` is 1GB file.

If yes, is there a way to get a part of a large module without loading all of it?

Thanks.

Comment: It has to load and run all the code in the module in order to ensure that the portion of the module you actually want will work.

Comment: "while someModule is 1GB file" an entire *gigabyte* of *Javascript code*? Never mind in a *single file*? Madness!

Comment: @JaredSmith it's just theory bro :))

Comment: Dude, that's like saying I want a car that can go 1,000,000,000 km/h. Oh wait, it's only theory I actually only need to drive 100 km/h. The memory usage of any file that you'd actually load is exceedingly trivial.

Comment: _"If yes, is there a way to get a part of a large module without loading all of it?"_ You could split the module into multiple files.

Comment: I doubt any single module could ever actually grow to that size in a single file. The code would be so unwieldy and unmaintainable that it would either cease to function, or would be split into separate files out of sheer necessity.

Comment: Like Pointy said, the entire module is loaded. That encourages you to split your code into smaller reusable modules, that is the idea of the modules from the beginning.

Comment: Are you asking about the actual import step or the resulting artifact? You can use tree shaking to clean up the result.

Comment: @JaredSmith actually I'm thinking of creating a database specific for NodeJS. If I wanna store each collection as one module, it is probable to reach that amount of volume.

Comment: I saw compiled JS reaching 500+ MB, so it is not so theoretical... The environment almost always load the entire module, if you don't want this behaviour I suggest to use some lazy evaluation: `somePart` should be a function (or a getter) which executes and instantiate a value only when asked. Also to note that the environment usually parses only the parts of code it needs to execute and retains in memory just the "code" belonging to those. JIT compilers nowadays lighten memory consumption and also improved runtime speed in these cases

Comment: @DDomen "almost"?  No. ALWAYS. The entire file that is references via "require" is parsed and ***executed***. This is why required files can have side-effects, whether or not they export anything.

Comment: @Inigo if you are referring to the common NodeJS environments, yes is pratically "ALWAYS"... Also, native bounded modules can create other kind of context which are not "executed"  (or better parsed) on module loading since they are already in bytecode

Comment: @SoroushBgm data in a database is not the same thing as *code in the language the database engine was written in*. You're going to be storing your data in flatfiles, or json files, or binary files, or whatever: you're not going to be storing it as *executable Javascript* and grabbing it via `require`.